# How to filter through the post api response and get only the filtered array object from api response in angular?

Tags: angular, local-storage, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

**I have this getSearchBank() post API and this is the response of this api .**

**This api gives me all the banks which are present in the database**

```
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {bankId: '616c07ca9d60c50b84e8b71b', bankName: 'IDBI', branch: 'Annapurna Road', ifscCode: 'abc121132', address: {…}, …}
1: {bankId: '61f58ff918f67f5436cebc40', bankName: 'DENA', branch: 'Gopur', ifscCode: 'denabaanak'}
2: {bankId: '61f5901318f67f5436cebc41', bankName: 'ICICI', branch: 'GopurSQUAREeee', ifscCode: 'johnwick'}
3: {bankId: '61f7d8bb3c0b195e375a5846', bankName: 'ICICII', ifscCode: 'raju'}
4: {bankId: '61fbf0e013b9e42111aa7fd4', bankName: 'PNB', branch: 'footi Kothi sq', ifscCode: 'punjab'}
5: {bankId: '61fbf20b13b9e42111aa7fd5', bankName: 'AXIS Bank', branch: 'usha nagar', ifscCode: 'axis'}
6: {bankId: '61fd2a5751498106f78469ac', bankName: 'Kishkin Goldman sachs', branch: 'Kishkingold', ifscCode: 'goldman'}
7: {bankId: '61fd2eb251498106f78469ad', bankName: 'AnnapurnaRoad', branch: 'indiabank', ifscCode: 'indiabank'}
```

```
public getSearchBank(
    ifscCode: string,
     
    ){
const postData : Create = {
  ifscCode: ifscCode,
  address: '',
  city : '',
  bankId: '',
  bankName: '',
  branch: '',
  passBookNo: ''
}
{
return this.http.post('http://localhost:9900/api/v1/bank/search',postData)
.pipe(
  filter(data => {
    var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
    res.ifscCode === localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue")
  console.log("PIPE MAP OPERATOR CALLED!!!")
    console.log(res.body.ifscCode);
    console.log(res.body);
    return res
  }),
```

**Now the thing I want is that in the pipe method I want to iterate over the array which is coming in this post api response ,  or like I want to check that if localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue") is equal to ifscCode from one of these objects from the response , if the ifscode matches one of them then I want to get only that array object inspite of getting all the 8 array objects**

**Like if I explain in a simple manner suppose [ localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue") = johnwick ] then in the api response I want only the 2nd array which has the ifscCode as johnwick**

**I want this because in the future when I have more banks then there will be much load on the UI if I am loading all the array objects in the UI while calling the API**

Answer (score 1):

Check this stackblitz I've created to simulate your request:

[angular project sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2gsfw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

with map

```html
.pipe(
        map((list) => {
          const ifscCode === localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue")
          return list.find(element => element.ifscCode === ifscCode );
        })
```

with filter is not possible